# How to Handle an Exception in the Recursive setTimeout Pattern

Tags: node.js

If ws.send throws an exception for the code below, I want to ensure that I stop recursively sending and that the client thread ends.

```
function newAlarm(ws)
{
    ws.send(alarm);
}

function loop(f,t)
{
    setTimeout(() => loop(f,t), t);
    f();
}

loop(() => newAlarm(ws),10000);
```

I understand that to catch the error for `ws.send`, I do the following: `ws.send(alarm, err => {if(!err){...}})` But I can't figure out how to do this for setTimeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a variable to hold your timer, then clearing it when you want it to stop.

```
function newAlarm(ws)
{
        ws.send(alarm);
}

function loop(f,t)
{
    var timer = setTimeout(() => loop(f,t), t);
    try{
        f();
    }
    catch{
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
}

loop(() => newAlarm(ws),10000);
```

Comment: But newAlarm is no longer a pure function.

Comment: Can you put a try-catch around `f()` in your loop and call `clearTimeout(timer)` in the catch? It worked for a toy example I tried. I updated the code in my answer.

Comment: This works and I prefer it to your first answer, thanks!